# Problema com a urllib

Tags: python

Estou tentando resolver a python challege #4 mas quando eu executo minha possível solução eu obtenho um erro. A minha solução é a seguinte:

```
import urllib, re


pattern = re.compile("and the next nothing is \d")
text = "and the next nothing is 12345"
nothing = int(text[-5:])
check = re.search(pattern, text)

while check:  # main loop
    url = urllib.urlopen("www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing={}".format(nothing))
    text = url.read()
    nothing = int(text[-5:])
    check = re.search(pattern, text)

print text
```

e quando executo obtenho esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python_Challenge_4.py", line 12, in 
    url = urllib.urlopen("www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing={}".format(nothing))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 463, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 477, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345'
```

**Nota**: Eu não quero uma solução para a python challenge 4, apenas quero saber a causa desse erro.

Comment: já tentou colocar `http` no começo da url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso o método `urlopen` não identificar o `scheme` da URL (**http:**, **https:**, **file:**, etc) ele interpreta como a abertura de um arquivo local. Veja na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen):

> Open a network object denoted by a URL for reading. If the URL does
>   not have a scheme identifier, or if it has file: as its scheme
>   identifier, this opens a local file